# background image repeat with !important proper css code

Tags: css, media-queries

My goal is to change the background image at certain browser sizes using media queries.... 
I need it to override the element style as well so I need to have !important right after my background-image tag...

This is what have so far..

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 690px) and (max-width : 1000px) {
    #featured article[data-background-cover="1"] {
        background-image: url('#')!important;    
    }
}
```

The code above seems to work.. but i need the background image to repeat... how can i add that in while still preserving the !important.

I have tried a couple ways but it doesn't seems to work.. like

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 690px) and (max-width : 1000px) {
    #featured article[data-background-cover="1"] {
        background-image: url('#')repeat!important;    
    }
}
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 690px) and (max-width : 1000px) {
    #featured article[data-background-cover="1"] {
        background-image: url('#')!important repeat;    
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background-image: url('#');
background-repeat: repeat;
```

You can also try this:

```
background-image: url('#');
background-repeat: repeat !important;
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You put **!important** with a space and at the end for each property.

But do try to avoid **!important** overall if possible and order your styles so that these would be applied correctly.

Comment: Yes, I do that normally. In this case, I'm selecting a image slider that has styles being added by javascript on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a container and you want apply different styles based on device screen resolution.

```
#container {
        /* triggered by all devices */
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 690px) and (max-width : 1000px) {
       #container { 
           /* triggered by devices with specified width */
       }
}
```

Thus the first selector will be applied to all devices, and if a specific media query matches, this selector will be overwritten. It's good to follow the order in which you add the styles as they are rendered from top to bottom, so if you have two identical selectors with different styles, the one underneath will have highest priority.

Anyway, this is correct shorthand notation for `background` property:

```
background: #000 url() repeat fixed left top !important;
```

**Order:** Background Color, Background Image, Repeat, Position, Position X, Position Y, Important;